# Find prc change of every two columns value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take a data frame that has time series values on the row axis and get % change. 
For example here is the data:

```
77 70 105
50 25 50
15 20 10
```

This is the required result:

```
-0.1 0.5
-0.5 1
0.33 -0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) over axis 1 and [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```
df
    0   1    2
0  77  70  105
1  50  25   50
2  15  20   10

df.pct_change(1).dropna(1)
          1    2
0 -0.090909  0.5
1 -0.500000  1.0
2  0.333333 -0.5
```

Comment: Is there a way to write my own % change formula? My issue is that I have some negative values so I want to be able to abs the denomintor